# ksh type with herestring

Tags: shell-script, ksh, here-document, typeset, here-string

I wanted to use Here String in conjunction with custom type in KSH. Unfortunately I am not able to tell what I am doing wrong.

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -T Type_t=(
   typeset string='aaa'
   function fc {
      cat <<< ${_.string}
   }
)

Type_t t
t.fc
```

gives me

```
script.ksh[10]: ct.fc[5]: cat: not found [No such file or directory]
```

It's not the matter of printing content, I am interessted in using object's fields as Here String in commands like cat or grep

Comment: works for me. ksh --version: sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01. Do you perhaps have some non-printing character in the file. dump it with `cat -vet` to see.

Comment: I have the same symptoms when I execute it in standalone command line (without script file). My ksh is `version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21`